# оператор in python

Tags: python

как с помощью оператора in найти часть текста

```
v = input() # for i in range(10)
if v in "for": # почему питон считает что это ложь
    print(v)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что `if "for" in v:`

Comment: как сделать чтобы он нашел часть текста только с помощью for?

Comment: Что значит «с помощью for»?

Comment: пользователь вводит      for i in range(N) но пользователь может ввести не только for например как fjf;flfk и нужно определить где for а где нет

Comment: Ну так чем `if "for" in v:` не угодило-то?

Comment: Читайте просто по-русски то, что написано по-английски. `if "for" in v:` -> "Если [строка] "for" есть в [переменной] v:", может так понятнее будет, как использовать оператор `in`.

Comment: сейчас отправлю скрин секунду

Comment: На скрине написано вовсе не `if "for" in v:`

Comment: я вложил в вопрос сюда просто отправлять нельзя

Comment: Ну так это равно True, раз он текст вывел. Что непонятно-то?

Comment: а все понял спасибо я просто забыл что их  надо задом наперет

Comment: @Глеб на скрине не вывод, а ввод

Comment: Ну да, потому что "если строка в переменной", а не "если переменная в строке". Второй вариант тоже бывает используется, но в данном случае он не подходит.

Comment: не используй зарезервированые слова и инструкции в качестве примера

Answer (score 0):

v = input() - будет иметь тип строка.
При итерации циклом For по ней каждая итерация будет соответствовать 1 символу (неважно/пробел/буква/цифра/запятая).
Чтобы выполнить предполагаемую мной задачу, Вам необходимо с помощью l = v.split('<разделитель>') разделить строку на состовляющие списка и в списке уже искать соответствия.

```py
v = input()
l = v.slit(' ') # разобьёт строку по пробелам и наполнит список.
for n in l:
    if n == '<нужное значение>':
        print(f'В строке есть:"{n}"')
    else:
        print(f'В строке нет соответствия...')
```

Comment: _Зачем_ нужно разбивать строку? У автора вопроса такой задачи не стояло. Ему нужно было проверить вхождение подстроки в строку, и он это делал неправильно — вместо `if "for" in v` использовал `v in "for"`. А ваш ответ вообще не к его коду.

Comment: В этом случае пусть использует `v.find()` или `v.rfind()`.

Comment: `find()` нужен для определения индекса вхождения, а не самого факта вхождения. Нет, можно забить вазой гвоздь, но зачем?

Comment: Может вам стоит предложить решение , а не разглагольствовать со мной по поводу предложенных мной решений.

Comment: Я не разглагольствую. Это элементарнейшая задача и предлагать тут нечего. Вхождение подстроки в строку определяется одним-единственным способом — оператором `in`. При написании программ очень важно сохранять читабельность, и если пользоваться другими способами, это неизбежно усложнит понимание программы.